# Can I use DELETE to update a flag indicating that this element is deleted?

Tags: rest, http

I'm building an API and I want to follow best practice so I used PUT to insert, POST to update and GET to fetch, and I want to use DELETE when the client requests to delete an item but the thing is in the database we won't be actually deleting anything, we're simply **updating a flag indicating that this item is deleted**, so does that still fall under DELETE or should that request be POST instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you talking about is called "soft delete" - when a record is marked deleted, it is not available through GET, but data remains in the database. For all client purposes that is still a delete operation, implementation is your own and should not concern your clients.

So yes, it is perfectly fine to use HTTP verb DELETE to do a soft delete.

Answer (score 2):

From the client perspective, the data is not there anymore (it cannot see that piece of data if the client calls the GET endpoint), so you can use the DELETE verb for this endpoint.

One important thing to keep in mind is to stay [GDPR](https://www.eugdpr.org) compliant if the end-user is from an EU country (General Data Protection Regulation forces you to delete the user private data upon their request. Making the data unavailable to the user, but keeping it on your server (by flagging it as deleted) is a direct violation of the user rights).

Comment: There was nothing in the question to indicate type of data. For all we know it could be watches or coffee cups. So GDPR reference is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by others, you can use the HTTP DELETE method for this case.

Also, a small correction in the other standards you have mentioned. It has to be HTTP **POST to create** and **PUT to update** your resources.